Flutter Push Notification with spring boot
I have developed an application with Flutter which works seamlessly with Java Spring Boot on the backend. I use Firebase on the backend to send notifications to the Flutter application. Everything works fine when running on the local server, but when I connect the application to a remote server and deploy it live, the notifications stop working. I'm not receiving any errors, but the notifications simply don't arrive on the remote server.
Do you have any idea what could be causing this issue? Everything works locally but not on the remote server, and I'm not getting any error messages.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
